# Badrequest 400 при попытке загрузить картинку post-запросом на сайт,сделанный на wordpress, используя httpclient java

Tags: java, http, post, rest, fileupload

Подобный вопрос я уже задвавал [Bad request 400 при попытке загрузить post-запросом jpg картинку на сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1018696/bad-request-400-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc-jpg-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82).
Но к сожалению доступ к тому аккаунту я утратил и не имею возможности отвечать на вопросы. Sergi посоветовал убрать все header'ы, но ошибка так и осталась.

Попробовал сделать через CloseableHttpClient. Не помогло

```
    public void uploadImageToServer() {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://newsprice.info/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php");
        final HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8")).addBinaryBody("uploadfile[]", new File("/tmp/toon.jpg")).build();
        String contentType=entity.getContentType().getValue();
        httpPost.setHeader("Host", "newsprice.info");
        httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        httpPost.setHeader("Referer", "https://newsprice.info/account/?user=361&tab=postform");
        httpPost.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        //           request.setHeader("Content-Length", "668071");
        httpPost.setHeader("DNT", "1");
        httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpPost.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int status=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Привожу данные, которые отправляются, если загружать картинку вручную.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

curl запроса(он явно не полный, обрывается, когда начинается сам код картинки)

```
curl "https://newsprice.info/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------240931805532392" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://newsprice.info/account/?user=361&tab=postform" -H "Cookie: wordpress_sec_592fe6d56b5af5594c85ae06105919a9=Truman"%"7C1568797496"%"7CVbWtRNrRUbWUQge3NfmjnXr6X0G7Rk7pUT8E9CtahZn"%"7Cb436edf2e8873517002b66195a8c3a2fe734cd142649caae5ec35e829a32cd1d; _ym_uid=1567587635750295545; _ym_d=1567587635; _ym_visorc_54017002=w; _ym_isad=2; wordpress_logged_in_592fe6d56b5af5594c85ae06105919a9=Truman"%"7C1568797496"%"7CVbWtRNrRUbWUQge3NfmjnXr6X0G7Rk7pUT8E9CtahZn"%"7C8a76d9f2f832c246d9377f1a1fcaeec7dadd6d221346560e935129fdbbcb9e80; wpsp_user_session=eyJ0eXBlIjoxLCJuYW1lIjoiVHJ1bWFuIiwiZW1haWwiOiJncmVna3VrdWtldkB5YW5kZXgucnUifQ"%"3D"%"3D" --data-binary "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""action"""^

  ""^

  "rcl_imagepost_upload"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""post_type"""^

  ""^

  "post"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""post_id"""^

  ""^

  "0"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""form_id"""^

  ""^

  "1"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""ext_types"""^

  ""^

  "png, gif, jpg"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""size_files"""^

  ""^

  "2"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""max_files"""^

  ""^

  "10"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""ajax_nonce"""^

  ""^

  "803160d401"^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392"^

  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile[]"";                filename=""toon.jpg"""^

  "Content-Type: image/jpeg"^

  ""^

  "-----------------------------240931805532392--"^

  ""
```

P.s. 
Может быть нужно каким-то образом перекодировать body запроса? Или отправлять только body?

Comment: Приложите curl этого запроса, а то тяжело со скрина.

Comment: я отправляю не curl'ом а через firefox. Нажимаю кнопку "Добавить картинку" и смотрю, что отправилось в post-запросе. Как тоже самое отправить curl'ом я не знаю.

Comment: @Victor, удалось скопировать curl. Сейчас обновлю данные

Answer (score 0):

Видно, что браузер шлет еще cookie вместе с безумным количеством хидеров. У вас не увидел посылку куки

Comment: в первой строчке есть отправка куков, влево нужно проскролить. Но куки тут не столь важны, я эксперементировал, в браузере убирал хедер с куками, пост запрос все равно проходил и картинка грузилась на сайт